# php SoapClient - make a call with multiple root tags in request

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

Here's the xml structure that I want to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:method>
      <auth>
        ...
      </auth>
      <data>
        ...
      </data>
    </ns1:method>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
</XML>
```

My code:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://www.test.com/soap.php",
                                     'uri'      => "http://tempuri.org/",
'trace' => true,'exceptions' => true,'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

$request = new stdClass();
$request->auth = new stdClass();
$request->data = new stdClass();

$client->__soapCall("method", array($request));
```

Please note: SoapClient doesn't allow me to insert anything other than array in second param to the `__soapCall` method.

So here's what I'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:method>
      <param0 xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
        <auth xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct"/>
        <data xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct"/>
      </param0>
    </ns1:method>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

As you can see, php added a root tag for my request - param0. Is there a way I can escape this? I need to have 2 "root" elements in that request parameter. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for answering. I solved the issue with the help of SoapParam:

```
$client->__soapCall("method", array(
    new SoapParam($request->auth, "auth"),
    new SoapParam($request->data, "data"),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try this way : `$client->__soapCall("method", $request);`?

Comment: there's type hinting which throws an exception if I'm trying to pass anything other than array in second parameter.

Comment: then did you try a WSDL to php generator that will ease you the way to sent the parameters? Try to took for WsdlToPhp or at https://www.wsdltophp.com

Comment: I'd try setting `'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT` in SoapClient constructor's options to get rid of `param0`.